# Get only the red channel in opencv workout white balance

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi3

I need to get the red component of the camera feed using opencv. I know that the red channel can be extracted from the image, but my problem is AWB. So right now, even if I shine a pure green light, I can see the red component showing stuff. What I need, is to detect the original red colour without AWB.

I tried switching off the AWB and set the AWB gains, but this can only set the red and blue gains. I need to switch off the green and blue channel and just see the output. Is this possible?

Comment: 1) AWB? Auto White Balance? 2) Are you sure your green light contains only green? 3) Please elaborate about turning AWB off, camera lense etc 4) How large are the red values you are getting when theoretically only green light is caught? Maybe it's negligible?

Comment: 1) AWB: yes, auto white balance, 2) I have a nice filter which filters out anything except a small spectrum of green.3) I'm on a rapsberry pi and I used the picamera to set AWB to off. This gives me a black screen and after which I need to set the awb_gains. The camera lens is the default one that comes with the camera. I checked the full RGB response with the AWB active. When I shine a green light, the display quickly makes it look whiter. The green light is now visible whiter. 4) I'll check the intensities of red. That's a great suggestion!

Comment: But I'm thinking the AWB will leak the green to red channel to make the image match the original colour.